# How to run some code at the end of pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, dataflowtask

I have a requirement to update two tables at the end of the dataflow job pipeline(based on pipeline result).

I have put my logic to update to tables in finally block.

Here finally block is executing in parallel to the pipeline

Is there a way where i can run the code at end of pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer suggested by @robertwb to use waitUntilFinish() may not work in GCP. Refer to the link and explanation from Google Cloud Docs. However, We can try to achieve the final step as part of the pipeline itself by using Combine.globally() as the last step in the pipeline.

// sample pipeline

```
            pipeline.apply("step_1", ParDo.of(step_1()))
                .apply("step_2", ParDo.of(step_2()))
                .apply("step_3", ParDo.of(step_3()))
                .apply("step_4_wait_until_finish", combineGlobally())
                .apply("step_5_final", ParDo.of(new Step_5_final()));
```

// combineGlobally

```
    static Globally<TableRow, TableRow> combineGlobally() {
    return Combine.globally(new SerializableFunction<Iterable<TableRow>, TableRow>() {
        @Override
        public TableRow apply(Iterable<TableRow> input) {
            return new TableRow();
        }
    }).withoutDefaults();
}
```

// Step_5_final

```
    static class Step_5_final extends DoFn<TableRow, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void onElement(@Element final TableRow dataIn, final OutputReceiver<String> out) throws Exception {
        BigQuery.execute(update_query_1);
        BigQuery.execute(update_query_2);
        out.output("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Refer to this link https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#limitations

The following limitations apply to Flex Templates jobs in GCP:

- The program that constructs the pipeline must exit after run is called in order for the pipeline to start.
- waitUntilFinish (Java) and wait_until_finish (Python) are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The PipelineResult object should have a [waitUntilFinish](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html#waitUntilFinish--) operation that you can call from within your try block to ensure the pipeline completes before the finally block executes.

Comment: Code mentioned after waitUntilFinish() is not working in the DataFlowRunner. Is there any other option? Please advise.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "not working?" Is the pipeline failing and an exception getting thrown (in which case you can catch it and put your post-pipeline code there)?

Comment: waitUntilFinish() throws an exception soon after the pipeline starts. so adding a catch block to perform my pipeline cleanup will get executed immediately even before my pipeline is completed.

Comment: Could you add some details to your question about what exception is thrown?